# git aws.push returned error 403

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm working on getting git setup for my application on Elastic Beanstalk. I've been following the instructions provided by amazon. After pushing the changes I get this error

git aws.push

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 403 while accessing https://<Access Key             Removed>:20130117T213945Z538f1c7baf8c89b4b547cb6717aabbaa7dfab3c52e0911d71e17b06765b922b2@git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/54696d73546573744170706c69636174696f6e/commitid/62323130316462646264373436303536343265633861333035633133633265666466393633303133/environment/54696d7374657374656e7669726f6e6d656e74/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Here's my .config file

git config -l

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=Tim xxxxxxxxxx
user.email=xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
core.bare=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
aws.endpoint.us-east-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-northeast-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.eu-west-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.us-west-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.us-west-2=git.elasticbeanstalk.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-southeast-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.ap-southeast-2=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
aws.endpoint.sa-east-1=git.elasticbeanstalk.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.remote=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push --remote-url
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.push=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
alias.aws.elasticbeanstalk.config=!.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
alias.aws.push=!git aws.elasticbeanstalk.push
alias.aws.config=!git aws.elasticbeanstalk.config
```

How can I check the permissions on amazon's side? Is it a security group setting?

Thanks for your help. Please let me know if I can provide you with additional info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS git plugin returns 403 if your system clock is off by over 900 seconds.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how do we fix the skew in the system clock?

Comment: Jesus, I would have never guessed, thanks so much for your comment!

Comment: Thanks for posting this would never have got it otherwise